# Woocommerce PHP add_to_cart causes duplicated cart data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I am adding hidden fields to the product page to allow customers to select an up sell during the add to cart process.

```
<form class="variations_form cart">
    [...]
    <input type="hidden" name="cross_sell[26831]" id="cross-sell-26831" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cross_sell[33484]" id="cross-sell-33484" value="1" />
    [...]
</form>
```

The following code in functions.php handles adding up sell items to the cart.

```
add_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', 'add_up_sells_to_cart', 1);

function add_up_sells_to_cart() {

    $cross_sells = $_POST['cross_sell'];
    if(!is_array($cross_sells)) return;

    foreach($cross_sells as $product_id => $quantity) {

        if($quantity > 0) {
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

            if ($product->is_type('variation')) {
                $cart_id = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product->get_parent_id(), $quantity, $product_id, wc_get_product_variation_attributes( $product_id ));
            } else {
                $cart_id = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

All products are added to the cart but the up sells appear to be inheriting attribute data from the main product.

[image]

I have tried:

- Using `unset()` to null `$_POST` temporarily while adding up sells to the cart, in case the `add_to_cart()` helper function is somehow detecting the presence of the $_POST vars.
- Adding both simple and variable products, the problem is present on both product types
- Changed the hook to `woocommerce_add_to_cart`, the problem persists and also this causes a endless loop as the function code triggers the hook again

How can I prevent this data duplication in the cart?

Comment: since WooCommerce 3.3.0, attributes are no more shown under the name but in the title. do you have a plugin which change that ?

Comment: @Kaperto yes thank you. It is my code which causing this. Not an issue with WP Core